# Bash export different tables from 96 databases

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, bash, count

first excuse me for my english i'm from switzerland :)

I need help with my Bash script to export tables with different prefixes from different mySQL databeses.
I have to export a column named "introtext" from 96 databeses and in every db the tablenames have diefferent prefixes.

With my current script it only exports the first table from first db, my counter counts up but doesnt change the tablename and db...

The tablename and databasename in the variables are listed in the right/same order.

Here my script with only 4 databeses from my test system.

```
#!/bin/bash

#MySQL Login Variablen
user=root
pass=pwd123

#Tebellenname Variablen
STRtbl="ebn8r_content,h4akd_content,vbm6h_content,fb2tz_content"

#DB Variablen
STRDB="DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4"

counter=0
countermax=95

#IFS=',' read -a ARRAYdb <<< "$STRDB"
#IFS=',' read -a ARRAYtbl <<< "$STRtbl"
IFS=","
ARRAYdb=($STRDB)
ARRAYtbl=($STRtbl)

while [ $counter -le $countermax ]
do

#Entfernt Counter von Tabellenname/remove counter from tablename
tblcount=$ARRAYtbl[$counter]
tbl=${tblcount%[*}

#Entfernt Counter von DB-Namen/remove counter from dbname
dbcount=$ARRAYdb[$counter]
db=${dbcount%[*}
        echo "$dbcount"
#MySQL Abfrage Variable
query="SELECT introtext FROM $tbl INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$db.csv' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"

#echo "$query"
        echo "Counter= $counter"
#Abfrage zusammenstellen und ausführen/build the full mysql query
for table in $(mysql -u$user -p$pass -D$db -Be "SHOW TABLES"); do
        echo "exporting $db"
mysql -u$user -p$pass -D$db -Be "$query"

counter=$[$counter +1]

        echo "$ARRAYdb[$counter]"
done
done
        echo "Export abgeschlossen"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an array element, you have to put `{}` around the variable:

```
tbl=${ARRAYtbl[$counter]}

db=${ARRAYdb[$counter]}
```

Comment: With tbl=${tblcount%[*} i remove the number "[n]" from the table and db name to use it in the query

Comment: There shouldn't be `[n]` in the table. Accessing an array element just retrieves that value.

Comment: when i add the {} like your example, mysql cant read the table and db name... then the query look like this: SELECT introtext FROM  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/.csv' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: The only reason you got `[n]` was because you weren't using the correct syntax for array accesses.

Comment: okay i removed the lines `tblcount=$ARRAYtbl[$counter]` and `dbcount=$ARRAYdb[$counter]` then i changed the both `db/tbl=${tblcount%[*}` to your example. but when i execute the script my echo of the query looks like this `SELECT introtext FROM  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/.csv' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';` without dbname and tablename

Comment: sorry my fault... only the echo outputs are without the names but the export works. great, thank you :)

Comment: Now my script exports the 4 tables from the right database. But now it finds no ending and i get the following echo:

`ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'SHOW TABLES'
export  from
SELECT introtext FROM  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/.csv' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Counter= 4`

Why do i get the ERROR message and why my echo doesnt show me the tbl and db names? Im not sure but is it possible, that the script doesnt find a ending, beacause of i only have 4 databases on my test system and the counter is adjustet to 96?

Comment: Of course. If there are only 4 databases, but you try access `${ARRAYdb[5]}`, you'll get an empty string. Why don't you use the size of the array instead of hard-coding the max?